# PHP query - How to compare two columns from different tables to match one column

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry, I wasn't sure exactly what title to give this and have not been able to find any other posts regarding it though I am sure it must not be very difficult - I am just not aware of how to do it.

in a php query, I need to compare one column in my database with another column (on a different table) to see if they match (using == ). However, the second column on the other table that needs to be matched can only be determined by a third column located on the same table as the first column came from.

Before I make it sound more confusing that it probably is, here is a basic outline of what I need to achieve:

```
if ($this->prefix == $user->special_id ??? $table2['CODE']) {
```

I don't know what to put where the ??? is..

special_id is generated from table2 and on table two there is also a column called CODE - CODE is what is used to make the prefix on table 1

```
TABLE 1  
+--------+------------+  
| prefix | special_id |

TABLE 2  
+------------+------+  
| special_id | CODE |
```

Some how I need compare the `CODE` from table2 and see if it is equal to the `prefix` on table1.. the link being special_id on both tables

(CODE and prefix can often match which is why I need to check it)

Sorry if my explanation isn't clear enough, any suggestions would be much appreciated - I just don't know how to write the code between special_id and $table2['code'] to make them operate together so to speak.

Thank you for reading.

EDIT:

I have "A" version working, and although it normally achieves the right results for me, there are some situations when it doesn't (due to other factors), so I am still hoping to keep a similar type of line:

(this one does bring results but the results are not always correct (and I don't want to compare special_id to special_id, I need to compare prefix to the special_id's code from the other table) so if anyone can still help please make a suggestion)

if ($this->special_id == $user->special_id&&$this->prefix==$table2['CODE']) {

EDIT:  THE ANSWER

This would have been hard for anyone to answer without seeing all the code, but in case anyone happens to have a similar issue, here is the answer:

if ($this->prefix == $table2['CODE']) {

Half of cj's answer was right so have given the correct answer to him.

Comment: Forget about PHP for a second and ask yourself "How would I do this through a MySQL command?" Then, if there are any variables that need to be passed, prepare the MySQL command in PHP and insert the variables.

Comment: Basically the part I need to write properly is for me to take the special_id from table1, match it to the special_id in table2 then use the CODE value for that row in table2 and see if it is equal to the prefix that I have already pulled from table1 - does that make sense?

Comment: I have this one which is working: if ($this->special_id == $user->special_id&&$this->prefix==$table2['CODE']) {    BUT, the result just isn't what I need to achieve.. so I was hoping to edit this a bit to achieve the result I need

Comment: you should try SQL commands in a sexy environment, like phpMyAdmin. It's much much much better than experimenting with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using an ORM of some sort.  I don't recommend using an ORM in PHP, but if that is what you are doing, I'd try something like this:

```
if ($this->prefix == $user->special_id && $this->prefix == $table2['CODE']) 
{
}
```

Or this, for clarity:

```
if (($this->prefix == $user->special_id) && ($this->prefix == $table2['CODE'])) 
{
}
```

Comment: I just read that this method doesn't work for you.  Why doesn't it work?  What is not working correctly?

Comment: There are hundreds of rows of different special_id's in table2 - I need to some how make sure which special_id row it is (by using the special_id stored in table1) to then see if that particular row's CODE equals the prefix I have already pulled.  I think that is why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In terms of MySQL statement (which I would recommend you using), it would look like:

```
SELECT t1.special_id as special_id 
    FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
    ON t1.special_id = t2.special_id
WHERE t1.prefix = t2.CODE
```

Comment: I have this one working  if ($this->special_id == $user->special_id&&$this->prefix==$table2['CODE']) {  but the results it's achieving is just a bit wrong in certain circumstances so I was hoping to keep this type of line but changed a little to achieve the result I was after